# Set maximum number of rows for a ListView

Tags: java, android

This is a question about Android programming. I need to limit the maximum number of visible rows in my `ListView`.

In `onCreate` method I have the next code for my `ListView`:

```
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayListOfElements));
```

In `onPostExecute` method I have the next adapter:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>) arrayListOfElements.getAdapter();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

So I need to set a maximum number of rows for my adapter, I don't care if the `ListView` will be scrollable or not. Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

Do this in your base adapter (mList is your list of items to show in the listview):

```
public int getCount() {
    if (mList != null) {
        return Math.min(mList.size(), YOU_MAX_VALUE);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can handle that in the place where you add the items to "arrayListOfElements"

For example: Lets say the max items is 10

```
int maxItemsToDisplay;
if(nodeList.getLength() > 10)
    maxItemsToDisplay = 10;
else
    maxItemsToDisplay = nodeList.getLength();

for(int i = 0; i<maxItemsToDisplay; i++)
{
    ...
    arrayListOfElements.add(item(i));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return YOUR_LIMIT;
}
```

Using `BaseAdapter`'s `getCount()` method can help in this case.

Comment: If you have 3 list items and a limit of 20, this example would return 20. But wouldn't 3 be the right number to return? I don't exactly understand how this code could help ...

Comment: You need something like Math.min(list.size(), LIMIT):

Comment: if(list.size() < YOUR_LIMIT) YOUR_LIMIT = list.size()

Answer (score 0):

You can set a limit to your array (arrayListOfElements) or truncate it before the association with the adapter.
The truncate can be like this:

```
if(arrayListOfElements.size()>MAXCOUNT)
{
    for(int i=MAXCOUNT;i<arrayListOfElements.size();i++)
    {
        arrayListOfElements.remove(i);
    }
}
```

If you don't want to modify the original array you can do a copy of it:

```
ArrayList<String> copy=new ArrayList(arrayListOfElements);
```

Comment: No problem! If this answer helps you, mark it like the correct one for other with the same problem.